# Un-nesting a column data from bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch 2 columns from my data in big query. Below is my query:

```
SELECT user_id, ep FROM table_name limit 3
```

Now, event_params is a nested column. It has a key and value. Below is how the data looks like:

```
user_id   ep.key     ep.value.string_value    ep.value.int_value
1         origin             fcm                   null
2         origin             fcm                   null
3         screen             null                   4
          origin             auto                  null
             id              null                   97
```

Big query some how divides the column ep into key and values (stored in string or int). I would need data in the following format:

```
user_id ep.key  ep.value
1        origin   fcm
2        origin   fcm
3        screen   4
         origin   auto
           id     97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT ep.key AS key, 
      COALESCE(ep.value.string_value, CAST(ep.value.int_value AS STRING)) AS value
    FROM UNNEST(ep) ep
  ) ep
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_name` AS (
  SELECT 1  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('origin', STRUCT('fcm', NULL))] ep UNION ALL
  SELECT 2  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('origin', STRUCT('fcm', NULL))] ep UNION ALL
  SELECT 3  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('screen', STRUCT(NULL, 4)),
    STRUCT('origin', STRUCT('auto', NULL)),
    STRUCT('id', STRUCT(NULL, 97))
  ] ep   
)
SELECT user_id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT ep.key AS key, 
      COALESCE(ep.value.string_value, CAST(ep.value.int_value AS STRING)) AS value
    FROM UNNEST(ep) ep
  ) ep
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
```

with result

```
Row user_id ep.key  ep.value     
1   1       origin  fcm  
2   2       origin  fcm  
3   3       screen  4    
            origin  auto     
            vid     97
```

Another option can be useful in case if you need to group all rows with same user_id

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( ep.key AS key, 
    COALESCE(ep.value.string_value, CAST(ep.value.int_value AS STRING)) AS value
  )) ep
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`, UNNEST(ep) ep
GROUP BY user_id
```

like in below example with extra row in sample data

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_name` AS (
  SELECT 1  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('origin', STRUCT('fcm', NULL))] ep UNION ALL
  SELECT 1  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('origin2', STRUCT('fcm2', NULL))] ep UNION ALL
  SELECT 2  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('origin', STRUCT('fcm', NULL))] ep UNION ALL
  SELECT 3  user_id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('screen', STRUCT(NULL, 4)),
    STRUCT('origin', STRUCT('auto', NULL)),
    STRUCT('id', STRUCT(NULL, 97))
  ] ep   
)
SELECT user_id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( ep.key AS key, 
    COALESCE(ep.value.string_value, CAST(ep.value.int_value AS STRING)) AS value
  )) ep
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`, UNNEST(ep) ep
GROUP BY user_id
```

with result

```
Row user_id ep.key  ep.value     
1   1       origin  fcm  
            origin2 fcm2     
2   2       origin  fcm  
3   3       screen  4    
            origin  auto     
            id      97
```

if you would run first option against same data you would get below result

```
Row user_id ep.key  ep.value     
1   1       origin  fcm  
2   1       origin2 fcm2     
3   2       origin  fcm  
4   3       screen  4    
            origin  auto     
            id      97
```